# why update_attributes is not calling before_validation call back in my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails 2.3.8 version is there any particular reason why update_attributes doesn't trigger before_validation callback

```
class x < ActiveRecord::Base
before_validation :testing

def testing
  debugger
end
end
```

x.update_attributes(:name => "hello") doesn't trigger before_validation

Comment: your title says `update_attributes` and your question says both `update_attribute` and `update_attributes`, which do you mean? they are crucially different.

Comment: it is x.update_attributes only update_attribute have the format as update_attribute(name,value) it was a typo mistake you should have understood through the param format

Comment: what indication is there that your `testing` method isn't running? in your example the method has no body and IIRC, only returning `false` from a callback will halt the execution chain, not nil.

Comment: i have a debugger all the other debug points are working but its not going inside this debug point

Comment: In my tests it works perfectly fine.

Comment: that is what it is working on create but not on update_attributes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27412/discussion-between-suman-and-mike-campbell)

Answer (score 4):

The answer will be very clear to you if you Googled this method: [here is the documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attribute) which clearly states that `update_attribute` does not go through the validation process. You should use `update_attributes` instead if you want to trigger validations.

Comment: The original question mentions `update_attributes`, not `update_attribute`.